# Launching custom activity onBackpressed launches activity twice

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have this really weird problem I can't quite wrap my head around. I have been pondering on this for hours and I have absolutely no clue why my code is behaving like this.

I have a `Viewpager` from which images can be deleted, in order to give the illusion of real time updating I open the same activity every time a photo is deleted so the `viewpager's` content will change immediately and accordingly.

For this reason I have overridden `onBackPressed()` to make sure that when this method is initiated the user returns to the real past activity and not the activity with the original images. I've read posts about this and tried to do things such as remove the super method and add the finish() method but nothing seems to work.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //creates two instances of AccountApartementActivity

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

    add_button_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    delete_button_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Intent i = new Intent(ApartementEditActivity.this, AccountAndApartementActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    i.putExtra("fromActivity", "2");
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

}
```

In neither of the two activities' lifecycle methods I have overridden have I written code that tells the application to create the same activity twice, or I'm somehow overlooking it.

Weirdest thing is that this worked fine just a day ago but today I changed the data type of one of my variables inside my `PagerAdapter` method and ever since the `onBackPressed()` method has been broken.

Please let me know if I am missing something obvious, it happens a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the best practice to manipulate the activities stack this way. You could eventually run out of memory.

I don’t know how your photos are organized, maybe with a container layout like a gridview or a recyclerview?

Then you should update views with the adapter and the notifyDataSetChanged method.

Good luck !